# Insert wrapper around div without an ID or class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to insert a wrapper around two divs, one with a dynamically generated ID. The div with the random ID is dynamically generated. No matter what I try, the wrapper is getting inserted after the target div though.

Before wrapper

```
<div id="search">Search</div>
<div id="234234">Unknown</div>
<div id="list">List</div>
```

After wrapper

```
<div id="search">Search</div>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="234234">Unknown</div>
  <div id="list">List</div>
</div>
```

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="search">Search</div>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="234234">Unknown</div>
  <div id="list">List</div>
</div>
```

**EDIT**

I have decided to use CSS to reposition the elements so that I no longer need the wrapper.

Comment: When saying *"without ID"* do you mean `id=""` or no `id` attribute at all? - or really `id="???"`

Comment: something like <div id="234234"> but the ID is random and changes each time the page loads.

Comment: I made you a snippet. You can update it to be a [mcve]

Comment: _"No matter what I try"_ Please post your attempts

Answer (score 0):

Simply wrap the children!

```js
$("#wrapper").children().wrapAll("<div class='wrapper'/>")
```

```css
#wrapper { padding: 20px; }
.wrapper { background-color: gold; outline: 2px solid red; }
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="123456">has whatever ID</div>
  <div id="list">has id</div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Or, to target elements that actually **have any ID attribute** use the `"[id]"` selector:

```js
$("#wrapper").children("[id]").wrapAll("<div class='wrapper'/>")
```

```css
#wrapper { padding: 20px; }
.wrapper { background-color: gold; outline: 2px solid red; }
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="list123456">has id</div>
  <div id="list">has id</div>
  <div>Foo bar</div> 
  <div id="list234">has id</div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

**Before Edit:**

Use the `:not([id])` or / and `[id=""]` selectors if you want to target *"no ID attribute"* / or / *"empty ID attribute"* respectively:

```js
$("#wrapper").children("div:not([id]), div[id='']").wrap("<div class='wrapper'/>")
```

```css
#wrapper { padding: 20px; }
.wrapper { background-color: gold; outline: 2px solid red; }
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="">has no id</div>
  <div>has no attribute id</div>
  <div id="list">has id</div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I need to wrap two specific divs, not all of them. I updated my sample code. The id is not empty, just random.

Comment: @Junky if none of the above examples fit your problem - you're out of luck

Answer (score 0):

If you do not know the element `id`, you can still use a `class` attribute to access it. Give the element with the random `id` (and any other elements you want to move) a `class` attribute so you can access via JavaScript and manipulate the DOM. You can do it simply with no jQuery, like this:

```js
// Create the `div.wrapper` element
const wrapperEl = document.createElement('div');
wrapperEl.classList.add('wrapper');

// Create a reference to each element you want to make a child of `div.wrapper`
const childEls = document.querySelectorAll('.wrapped');

// Move the elements from `body` to `div.wrapper` parent
wrapperEl.replaceChildren(...childEls);

// Append the `div.wrapper` to the body element
const bodyEl = document.querySelector('body')
bodyEl.appendChild(wrapperEl);

console.log(wrapperEl.outerHTML);
```

```html
<div id="search">Search</div>
<div id="234234" class="wrapped">Unknown</div>
<div id="list" class="wrapped">List</div>
```

I've logged the `wrapperEl` HTML in the console, but you can also inspect the HTML in your dev tools "Elements" tab to see the wrapper.

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/replaceChildren#transferring_nodes_between_parents